# Rooting the android subsystem on a Acer Chromebook R11

Tags: root-access, chrome-for-android, google, chromebook

I already have my chromebook in developer mode. 
I have play store apps enabled. 
How do I root the android os on my chromebook, so I can use apps like AdAway?

I have tried the commands

```
sudo /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions $(( $(rootdev -s | sed -r 's/.*(.)$/\1/') - 1))    
curl -Ls https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nolirium/aroc/onescript/RootandSEpatch.sh | sudo sh    
curl -Ls https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nolirium/aroc/master/01Root.sh | sudo sh    
curl -Ls https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nolirium/aroc/master/02SEPatch.sh | sudo sh
```

and I still get the following message from root checker.
[image]

Comment: background/source https://www.xda-developers.com/root-android-subsystem-chromebooks

Comment: "Please check the output of this script for any errors."